# setting offsetLeft on a react ref

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to reset a sliding containers offsetLeft property after a state change, similar to [this blog](https://medium.com/codezillas/interacting-with-dom-elements-in-react-e7e409d7874e) which seems to do it like so:

```
this.ref.scroller.offsetLeft -= 200
```

the above example is using a react class component.

I'm trying to do similar with a functional component:

```
sliderRef.current.offsetLeft -= 200
```

But my slider components offsetLeft does not change at is seems to be a read only property.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking after [`scrollLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft).

`sliderRef.current.scrollLeft -= 200`